# How to check element triggered by onBlur has certain class with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

HTML

```
   <input type="text" id="trainingFee" name ="training Fee" class="number error" value="" onblur="callMe()">
```

jQuery

```
    function callMe(){
       if($this.id).hasClass('error')){
        alert("has error class");       
 }
```

}

but this is not working. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to access the current id of the element using the ***this*** context..
You need to pass it to the function in order to do it

**onblur="callMe(this)"**

```
 function callMe(elem){
       if($(elem).hasClass('error')){
        alert("has error class");       
 }
}
```

Otherwise you can try this approach

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/MTB3K/1/)

```
$(function() {
    $('#trainingFee').on('blur', function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass('error')) {
            alert("has error class");
        }
    });
});​

<input type="text" id="trainingFee" name ="training Fee" class="number error" value=""  />
```

​

Answer (score 2):

You should remove the `onblur` attribute from HTML and just do it all with jQuery.

```
$('#trainingFee').blur(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass('error')) {
        alert('has error class');
    }
}​);​
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
if ($(this).is('.error')) {
  ...
}
```